# Sanity HTTP API: How to add an array of references?

Tags: sanity

What is the correct way to add an array of references using the [Sanity HTTP API](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-mutations#95bb692d7fb0)?

I'm able to add a single reference:

```js
const mutations = [{
  createOrReplace: {
    _id: '123',
    _type: 'cms.article',
    title: 'An article',
    author: {
      _ref: '12f90f00-8cfb-4161-8bea-26180',
      _type: 'reference'
    },
  }
}]
```

I expected adding an array of references to existing `tags` would work (it returns with Status 200)

```js
const mutations = [{
  createOrReplace: {
    _id: '123',
    _type: 'cms.article',
    title: 'An article',
    author: {
      _ref: '12f90f00-8cfb-4161-8bea-26180',
      _type: 'reference'
    },
    tags: [
      {
        _ref: 'foo',
        _type: 'reference'
      },
      {
        _ref: 'bar',
        _type: 'reference'
      },
    ]
  }
}]
```

But Sanity Studio crashes with `Error: Unsupported path segment {}` when I attempt to view the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to break this down:

First, a reference is an object that contains a `_type` and a `_ref`. The `_type` will always be `'reference'` and the `_ref` will always be the `_id` of the document you're referencing.

Second, an array can be either an array of strings or of objects. Either way, any item in an array needs a unique `_key`.
So, putting all of that together, your mutation would look like this:

```
field: [
  {
    _key: '<some-uuid>'
    _ref: '<_id-of-document>',
    _type: 'reference'
  },
]
```

When it comes to generating keys, you can use an external package ([uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) is common) or if you're using the JS client [auto generate keys](https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client#adding-elements-to-an-array) by passing `{ autoGenerateArrayKeys: true }` to your commit().

Comment: rdlp - Thanks for your suggestions.   But specifically what should the mutation look like for Sanity's REST API?   Could you give an example for my `tags` code?

Comment: I did! If you read the example I gave, that’s exactly what your tags array would look like in a mutation. If you’re still not understanding, you need to replace the field name with the field you’re writing (in your case tags) and then add in a uuid (refer to my previous answer if you don’t understand what a uuid is) and the ID of the document you’re referencing. I don’t have access to your data so I can’t tell you exactly what the ID value would be.

Comment: Ah, so you truly must create your own arbitrary `_key` to reference a document that already exists?   Interesting!  But works!  Any pointers where I can read more about that in the *HTTP API* docs?  I don't see any reference to requiring a `_key` for arrays of mutations in https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-mutations

Comment: I don’t think it’s mentioned in that page of the docs! It’s more likely somewhere in the page where the array schema type is described.